# How to create and change the colors in an array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript and trying to understand how json arrays work from w3school but getting no luck. My goal is to create a json that display a list of information like below after a button is clicked on the screen.(Sorry if not formatted correctly first post.)

Name: Tim
 Favorite Color: Blue
Home Address: 111 livington Road.

Name: Sara
Favorite Color:Pink
Home Address: 222 Learning Road.

etc...

I would like the text name of the person to have its favorite color. If I have a list of 4 different people with different colors.

```js
var myObj, i, j, x="";    
myObj = {
  "name": ["Tim","Sara","John","Billy"
  "Favorite_Color":"Blue","Pink","Yellow","Green"
  "Address": "111 Livington Road","222 Learning Road","333 JavaScript 
Lane","444 I'm lost road"}

for (i in myObj.name){
x += "<h2> + myObj.name[i] + "</h2>";
  for (j in myObj.name[i].favorite_colors) {
   x += myObj.name[i].favore_colors[j]; }
}
```

Link to an image of roughly what I am looking for

[image: Link to an image of roughly what I am looking for:]

Comment: You have a **JavaScript** array. JSON is a string format for representing JavaScript data structures. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Oh well than I am even more confused than I thought. This is almost a copy of the w3School site examples. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp.

Comment: @BLUES, Phil is just correcting your terminology. JSON is a string always, and you parse it into actual arrays / objects in your language of choice (in this case JavaScript). You use `JSON.parse` to convert a string into JavaScript objects, and `JSON.stringify` to concert your objects into a string representation of them. JSON is simply a string that can represent complex data structures, in order to pass information between systems (browser and server, for example). https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_parse.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Answer (score 0):

The object I suppose should be

```
myObj = {
    name: ["Tim","Sara","John","Billy"],
    Favorite_Colors: ["Blue","Pink","Yellow","Green"],
    Address: ["111 Livington Road","222 Learning Road","333 JavaScript Lane","444 I'm lost road"]
}
```

And you can loop on the `myObj.name` and by `index` you get the `Favorite_colors` of the person, like this:

```
let x = '';
myObj.name.forEach(function(name, index){
    x += '<h2 style="color: ' + myObj.Favorite_Colors[index] + '>"' + name +'</h2>'
});
```

But let me add an advice, you can restructure your `myObj` to:

```
myObj = [
    {name: 'Tim', favoriteColor: 'blue', address: '111 Livington Road'},
    {name: 'Sara', favoriteColor: 'Pink', address: '222 Learning Road'},
    {name: 'John', favoriteColor: 'Yellow', address: '333 JavaScript Lane'},
    {name: 'Billy', favoriteColor: 'Green', address: '444 I\'m lost road'},
]
```

This is an array of objects, which we can then loop on each object easier (without having to use the index), like this:

```
let x = '';
for (let item of myObj) {
    x += '<h2 style="color: ' + item.favoriteColor + '">' + item.name +'</h2>'
}
```